# Natural ordering with respect to sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across this question at the beginning of a real analysis book:

Under the natural ordering, which of the following are sequences?

(a) all integers

(b) all integers ≥− 100

(c) all integers ≤ 0

The answer is "only b".

But doesn't the natural ordering just mean putting the members of the sequence in correspondence with the naturals? And if so, what's wrong with these expressions and thus my answer of "all of them"? By the way, the book never explicitly defines a "natural ordering".

(I am sure that my expression for (a) can be more succint, but this still works)

(a) $\frac{n-mod(n,2)}{2}(-1^n),\ n\geq1$

(b) $\{n-100\},\ n\geq0$

(c) $\{-n\},\ n\geq0$

If my answers for (a) and (c) do indeed generate the sequences in question and are indeed in correspondence with the naturals, but are apparently wrong, does this mean I am wrongly interpreting "natural ordering"?

Thanks!

edit: fixed (a) to start with n=1

Comment: I guess one could view it as a matter of interpretation. But the natural interpretation of "the natural ordering" is the ordinary ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence has a first element, then a second one, etc.  Under the natural ordering, the first element has to be smaller than all the others.  There is no such element in (a) and (c).

Comment: So does a "naturally ordered sequence" mean a "strictly increasing sequence"?

Comment: It means the one that occurs to you naturally. In this case, it's the one that puts them in increasing order.

Comment: I will take that as a 'yes'. Thank you!